# Select from two tables without CommonElement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want making select from two tables without any common element
I'm trying this code, but I get incorrect syntax near ','.

```
select top 1 inventory.name, customer.name
from inventory
where inventor.name='test' ,  customer where customer.name='test2'
```

Comment: So you want two totally unrelated names, one from inventory and one from customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It leads to cartesian product of two tables. (Cross Join). Try like this,

```
SELECT TOP 1 i.NAME
    ,c.NAME
FROM inventory i
cross join customer c
WHERE i.NAME = 'test'
    AND c.NAME = 'test2'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `where` clause doesn't use `,` for conditions.  You want either `and` or `or` to connect conditions.  You also need a `join`.

So, I think you intend:

```
select top 1 i.name, c.name
from inventory i cross join
     customer c 
where i.name = 'test' and c.name = 'test2';
```

Normally, there would be a `join` condition for the `join`, but your question doesn't suggest one.  This would be expected:

```
select top 1 i.name, c.name
from inventory i cross join
     customer c 
     on i.customer_id = c.customer_id
where i.name = 'test' and c.name = 'test2';
```

But, then again, you are restricting the `name` columns in the `where` clause, so why not just do:

```
select 'test', 'test2';
```

and dispense with using the tables entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a query like below for the desired output.Assuming you need only top 1 column..

```
SELECT (SELECT top 1 i.name
        FROM inventory i 
        WHERE i.name = 'test') InventoryName,
       (SELECT TOP 1 c.name
        FROM customer c 
        WHERE c.name = 'test2') Customername
```